# how initialize a torch of matrices

Tags: python, pytorch

Hello I m trying to create a tensor that will have inside N matrices of n by n size. I tried to initialize it with

```
Q=torch.zeros(N, (n,n))
```

but i get the following error

```
zeros(): argument 'size' must be tuple of ints, but found element of type tuple at pos 2
```

Also I want to fill it later with random matrices with integer values and I will turn it to semidefinte so I thought of the following

```
for i in range(0,N):
   Q[i]=torch.randint(0,10,(n,n))
Q = Q*Q.t()
```

Is it correct? Is there any other faster way with a build in command?

Answer (score 3):

`N` matrices of `n x n` size is equivalent to three dimensional tensor of shape `[N, n, n]`. You can do it like so:

```
import torch

N = 32
n = 10
tensor = torch.randint(0, 10, size=(N, n, n))
```

No need to fill it with `zeros` to begin with, you can create it directly.

You can also iterate over `0` dimension similar to what you did:

```
for i in range(0, N):
    tensor[i] = tensor[i] * tensor[i].T
```

See [@Dishin H Goyani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63885307/10886420) answer for faster approach with permutation.

Answer (score 2):

- Here you supposed to pass `N, n, n` to get `N` matrices of `n` by `n` size. As @Szymon already explain in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63885069/6075699)

```py
Q = torch.randint(0, 10, size=(N, n, n))
```

- For Later part you can use [`torch.Tensor.permute`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute) to transpose internal tensors

```py
Q = Q * Q.permute(0, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `torch.empty` to create uninitialized tensor (it's faster then `torch.zeros`) [torch.empty](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.empty.html?highlight=empty#torch.empty)

```py
Q = torch.empty(N, n, n)
```

2. Initialize it:

```py
for i in range(0, N):
    Q[i] = torch.randint(0, 10, (n, n))
```

3. use `.permute` as @Dishin H Goyani has proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` operator on **iterables** like tuples to pass it as **positional arguments**.
Here sample code:

```
>>> import torch
>>> N = 2
>>> n = 3
>>> Q = torch.zeros(N, *(n, n))
>>> Q
tensor([[[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]],

        [[0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0.]]])
```